# MBP Retina 16" 2019: Screen flickering with colors

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, graphics, gpu

Every few weeks the screen on my Macbook Pro 16" starts doing this:

[image]

It happens only with some windows and sometimes the only thing that helps is restart. I went to the Apple store and they just told me to reinstall macOS which I don't really want to do as 1/ I don't have time for that, and 2/ I don't believe it will help.

Could this be a graphic card issue? Is this known issue?

[image]